# entering a string into scanf with a while < 0 condition causes infinite loop

Tags: c, string, while-loop

I have a "minutes" variable that I'd like the user to enter a positive number into.

```
int main(void)
{
    float minutes;
    minutes = -1;
    printf("Find out how many bottles worth of water your showers use!\n");
    printf("How many minutes do you spend in the shower? ");
    scanf("%f", &minutes);
    while(minutes < 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive number: ");
        scanf("%f", &minutes);
    }
}
```

It works as intended for numbers. If minutes >= 0, it accepts it, and if minutes < 0 it keeps asking. If I enter a string it infinitely loops

```
printf("Please enter a positive number: ");
```

and never gives me a chance to enter a new value. Why is this and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What do you intend with this program? What do you mean with negative and positive minutes?

Comment: Note that `scanf` isn't the safest way to get input in the first place, especially seeing as you want to handle the different possibilities of input.  See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

Comment: Why is the title phrased as if this is a bug in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't enter a numerical value, whatever you types stays in the input buffer.  You can check for this by reading the return value of `scanf`, which tells you the number of items read.  If it is 0, you can use `getchar` to read characters until the next newline to flush the buffer.

```
int main(void)
{
    int rval, c;
    float minutes;
    minutes = -1;
    printf("Find out how many bottles worth of water your showers use!\n");
    printf("How many minutes do you spend in the shower? ");
    rval = scanf("%f", &minutes);
    if (rval == 0) {
        while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));
    }
    while(minutes < 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive number: ");
        rval = scanf("%f", &minutes);
        if (rval == 0) {
            while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare and set 'rval' in the first pass?

Comment: @user3078414 Missed a copy/paste there.  Fixed.

Comment: Great solution. +1 for using `getchar` which is the POSIX compliant way of clearing the buffer

Comment: You also have to set `rval` on the first `scanf` call, right?

Comment: @thedouglenz Right.  Fixed.

Comment: Or something like `while( (rval = scanf("%f", &minutes)) != 1 || minutes < 0) { if (rval == EOF) { printf("Ops...\n"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} if (rval == 0) { while (getchar() != '\n'); } printf("Please enter a positive number: ");  }`

Comment: @dbush Thanks! I understand the problem now. Can you explain how while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF)) works? It seems like there's just a condition and nothing actually being done, yet it clears the input buffer?

Also it appears that in the second while, instead of rval = scanf("%f", &minutes); you can just use scanf("%f", &minutes); Does rval automatically get "updated?"

Comment: @NicholasHassan There's more than once thing happening in the `while` loop at once.  It calls `getchar` to get a character from the buffer and assigns it to `c`, then we test to see if `c` is either a newline or EOF.  Because the call to `getchar` happens as part of the conditional, the loop has an empty body.  It's equivalent to `do { c = getchar(); } while ((c!='\n') && (c!=EOF));`

Comment: @NicholasHassan You still need to assign the return value of `scanf` to `rval`.  Otherwise it will contain whatever value it had from the last time `scanf` was called.  Doing `rval = scanf(...` assigns the value of *that particular function call* to `rval`.  It does not permanently associate `rval` with what `scanf` returns whenever it is called.

Comment: @dbush Thanks again! The first part makes perfect sense. I see your point in the second one too - it just turns out that the code accidentally works such that you don't need the second rval. If a positive number is successfully entered, that whole while loop is skipped since minutes > 0. Crazy!

Answer (score 2):

The `%f` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to stop reading input as soon as it sees a character that isn't part of a legal floating-point constant (i.e., something that isn't a digit, decimal point, or sign).  That bad character gets left in the input stream, so the next call to `scanf` fails, and the next, and the next, etc.

You should always check the return value of `scanf` - it will tell you how many items were successfully read and assigned from the input stream.  In this case, you're expecting a single item, so you should get a return value of 1.  If you get a return value of 0, then it means the input is not a proper floating point value, and that bad input has to be cleared somehow.  Here's one possible solution:

```
if ( scanf( "%f", &minutes ) == 1 )
{
  // process minutes as normal
}
else
{
  // clear everything up to the next whitespace character
  while ( !isspace( getchar() ) )
    ; // empty loop 
}
```

The only problem with this is that `scanf` is kind of dumb, and if you type something like `123fgh`, it will convert and assign the `123` while leaving `fgh` in the input stream; you would probably want to reject that whole input completely.

One solution is to read the input as text, and then convert it using `strtod`:

```
char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // where BUFSIZE is large enough to handle expected input
...
if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) )
{
  char *chk; // chk will point to the first character *not* converted; if
             // it's anything other than whitespace or the string terminator,
             // then the input was not a valid floating-point value.
  double tmp = strtod( buffer, &chk );
  if ( isspace( *chk ) || *chk == 0 )
  {
    minutes = tmp;
  }
  else
  {
    // input was not a proper floating point value
  }
}
```

This has the benefit of not leaving crap in the input stream.

Comment: Note: This code would accept input like `"123 abc"` as valid input. Yet using `fgets()` is a good approach.